# How to hide the border line in firefox when click on the navigation bars?

Tags: firefox, border

Can check out [here](http://51hired.com)

[alt text http://51hired.com/static/problem.bmp](http://51hired.com/static/problem.bmp)

Comment: Exactly which browser version are you finding this problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS for the link element:

```
outline: 0px;
```